# iOS AES encryption and PHP decryption

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt a string in iOS and decrypt it with PHP.

In iOS I have the following code, based on the information in this link [AES-128 encryption in iOS and Decryption in PHP](http://tharindufit.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/aes128-encryption-in-ios-and-decryption-in-php/)

```
- (void)testCrypto {
    NSString *password = @"1234567891234567";
    NSString *plaintext = @"This is a test";
    NSString *encrypted = [plaintext AES128EncryptWithKey:password];

    dispatch_queue_t jsonParsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("jsonParsingQueue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{
        NSString *webResult = [EPWebServices cryptoData:[encrypted dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] password:password];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(testing:) withObject:webResult waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)testing:(id)test {
    test = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:test encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Result:%@", test);
}
```

The category on NSData used above to encrypt is in the link. `EPWebServices` is a class that converts the cipher text to base64 and sends a URLRequest to the server with the password and cipher text.

In PHP I have (also from the link above):

```
$Pass = $_GET['pw'];
$crypted = urldecode($_GET['encrypted']);        
$newClear = decrypt_password($crypted, $Pass);
echo "Dec: ".$newClear . "Input: ".$crypted;


function decrypt_password($pass,$key)
{
$base64encoded_ciphertext = $pass;

$res_non = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($base64encoded_ciphertext), ‘ecb’);
$decrypted = $res_non;
$dec_s2 = strlen($decrypted);

$padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s2-1]);
$decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);

return  $decrypted;
}
```

The problem is that the decrypted message is just an empty string. The result I get in NSLog is just `Dec:Input: ejhCNHo0Z2tNZ0paMGdJOTJLdEJjZz09`. I have confirmed that both the password and cipher text is received properly in PHP, however, the decryption only prints out an empty string. I am new to encryption, so there might be some basic errors. Please let me know if particular output/NSLog etc is needed.

Comment: You might want to do a NSLog(@"%@", encrypted); just after you encrypt your password. It will show that what you received in PHP in what you really sent with iOS. It is strange that your base64 string is not ending with ==

Comment: You were right, it was actually base64 encoded twice. However, fixing it did not fix the decryption. Any way to verify if it has been encrypted properly?